# jquery datepicker predefined date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my textbox where the datepicker is attached to:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="StartMonth" AutoPostBack="true" class="month-picker" />
```

and here is how I attach the datepicker. (I have multiple TextBoxes where the datepicker should be attached to, so I used the class attribute instead of the id.)

```
$(".month-picker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM yy', changeYear: true, yearRange: '-9:+9' });
```

When I click into the textbox where the text is "August 2012" it should set the pre-selected date of the datepicker to this date. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand anything what you want. You want that datepicker to select the current month if input contains `August 2012` ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes I believe by "this date" he's referring to the date in the textbox that he was just talking about, not today's date.